# newtxmath: an upright roman right subscript of a sans-serif upright math stands too close to it

Tags: subscripts, sans-serif, newtxmath, newtx, mathrm

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[helvratio=.9]{newtxtext}% Scale the sans font at 90% to somehow match the main serif font.
\usepackage[slantedGreek,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath}% Should be loaded after the text font according to its manual. The default uppercase Greek letters should be slanted according to the publisher's class (in a non-MWE example).  Subscript correction is for stuff such as ₁.
\begin{document}%
\(\mathsf{Struct}_{\mathrm{fin}}\)% denotes a finite structure
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` or `latex`+`dvips` produces a subscript which stands too close to the main expression (of which it is a subscript) in normal-size sans-serif:

[image: output]

For example, the space between “ﬁ” and “n” in “fin” is larger than the space before “ﬁn”. This is illogical because our subscript (as, I believe, most subscripts) is a semantic unit, so spaces around the subscript should be (in general, of course) larger than spaces inside the subscript.

Though we could solve the problem ad-hoc for this very position by adding space, say, via a positive `\mskip` or `\mkern`, is there a bug hiding anywhere and, therefore, a more systemic solution (when using `pdflatex` and `latex`+`dvips`)?

Comment: The side bearings for sans serif fonts are narrower than for serif fonts, and since this is upright, there isn't any italic correction, which would enlarge the gap.  I'm a bit surprised that there appears to be *no* right side bearing on the "t" and no left side bearing on the "fi", but I don't think it's a bug.  A small added space would definitely help.